# No Result Returned From SQL Query

Tags: sql

I am running the following query, but no rows are returned even though a record exists that should match the query.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    tblsignup
WHERE
     usr_email='amir@gmail.com'
AND
     (status=1 or status=2)
```

Comment: The query is valid. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: there is no out put, result avail in database

Comment: Does a record exist with a usr_email of 'amir@gmail.com' and a status of 1 or 2?

Comment: @Ardman: I would bet against that :)

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to run the query please.

Comment: What is the datatype of `usr_email` and `status`? What RDBMS are you using? What is the collation of your database (is it case sensitive). Are you sure there is no white space in your fields? Does `SELECT * FROM tblsignup WHERE usr_email='amir@gmail.com'` return any results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try by simplifying the query (yeah...even if it's so simple)

try this

> Select * from tblsignup

then

> Select * from tblsignup where
>   usr_email = 'amir@gmail.com'

then

> Select * from `tblsignup` where
>   `usr_email`='amir@gmail.com' and
>   status > 0

//I know you won't use > 0 at the end, but we want to eliminate the most cause of error we simplify by > 0 only to be easier to read

Tell us from where you start getting 0 line, this could lead us to the problem, I know I already had a problem like that with a field named "date", because date is already used by MySQL, funny MySQL still let me use that fieldname tho.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from `tblsignup` where `usr_email`='amir@gmail.com'  and  (`status`=1 or `status`=2)
```

I have a feeling "[status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html)" might be reserved for something special. It might be worth a shot changing it to `status`.

Comment: Can you post some extra code, are you using PHP to run the query?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping brackets around the `status` column name:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblsignup 
 WHERE usr_email = 'amir@gmail.com'
   AND ([status] = 1
    OR  [status] = 2);
```

**EDIT**
After reading your comment, why not use:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblsignup 
 WHERE usr_email = 'amir@gmail.com'
   AND [status] > 0;
```

Comment: there is three type of status 0,1,2. me just want those result whose status is 1,2

Comment: @amir Fayyaz: run SELECT [status] FROM tblsignup WHERE usr_email = 'amir@gmail.com' and tell us what the outcome is.

Comment: out put is zero but in database status is 2,

Comment: @amir Fayyaz: When you say the output is 0, how can this be if the status in the table is 2?  Do you have a usr_email of 'amir@gmail.com' in the table?

Answer (score 0):

May it be that your column or table has case sensitive collation and the address is typed different ('Amir...')? As your query is correct SQL. You can find that with:

```
EXEC sp_help DatabaseName
```